# WP8 - Get meta tags info from WebBrowser

Tags: windows-phone-8, meta, invokescript

I been trying to get the meta tag info from a webbrowser on WP8, but without success.

I tryed:

```
var myDesc = (string)myBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", " $('meta[name=description]').attr('content');");
```

and this...

```
string jsString = "";
jsString += "  var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); ";
jsString += "  var data = 'test'; ";
jsString += "  var mLen = metas.length; ";
jsString += "  for(var i=0;i<mLen;i++){ ";
jsString += "    if(metas[i].getAttribute('name').toLowerCase() == 'description'){ ";
jsString += "      data = metas[i].getAttribute('content'); ";
jsString += "    } ";
jsString += "  } ";

myBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { jsString });
var myDesc = (string)myBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", "data;");
```

and this...

```
myBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "var desc = document.getElementsByName('description')[0].getAttribute('content');" });
```

and all finish with error:

> {System.SystemException: An unknown error has occurred. Error:
>   80020101.    at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(Int32 hr)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(String
>   scriptName, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName,
>   String[] args) ...

Can somebody help me?

Best Regards!!

Answer (score 0):

First add WebBrowser in xaml and set IsScriptEnabled to true.

```
<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowser" Source="http://www.baidu.com/" IsScriptEnabled="True"/>
```

Second register the events: LoadedCompeted and ScriptNotify

```
webBrowser.LoadCompleted += webBrowser_LoadCompleted;
webBrowser.ScriptNotify += webBrowser_ScriptNotify;
```

Third inject the javascript code

```
void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval",@"window.Init=function(){var metas=document.getElementsByTagName('meta');var str='';for(i=0;i<metas.length;i++){str+='name:'+metas[i].getAttribute('name')+',content:'+metas[i].getAttribute('content')+';;}window.external.notify(str);}");
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("Init");
}
```

finally you get your meta info in webBrowser_ScriptNotify event

```
void webBrowser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Value);
}
```

Hope this helps :D

Comment: Same error:
{System.SystemException: An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.NativeMethods.ValidateHResult(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.InvokeScript(String scriptName, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.InvokeScript(String scriptName, String[] args)
   at xxxxxxxx.myBrowser_LoadCompleted...

Comment: @GabrielGómez ';;} in script delete one ;... I can get the correct info of meta.